# call function on the minute every minute

Tags: javascript

The code I wrote to call a function on the minute every minute, I think is flawed, as It's good for a while, but tends to lag behind by about 15 seconds for every hour since the page was loaded. To be honest I can't figure out what's causing the lagging, maybe it's the time it takes the functions to execute, small lapses all adding up and accumulating. Is there a way to auto-correct the lapses within the function as it's called. Or maybe someone knows a better method of achieving on the minute function calls. Any help or ideas much appreciated. Thanks.

```
var now = new Date();
var delay = 60 * 1000; // 1 min in msec
var start = delay - (now.getSeconds()) * 1000 + now.getMilliseconds();

setTimeout(function setTimer() {
  onTheMinFunc();
    setTimeout(setTimer, delay);
}, start);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not use `setInterval(setTimer, delay);`?

Comment: I think because it shouldn't happen every 60 seconds, but on the 0th second of a minute, according to the system clock.

Comment: @rob M I have done with this but the problem is identical, and I need to use timeout first anyway to offset the time difference. so If someone loaded the page at 10:00:40. it would call the function first time in 20 seconds

Comment: @user2014429 maybe i'm joining a bit late, but please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timers and javascript times aren't very accurate, and I would think the only way to make sure a function is executed every whole minute over time, is to check the seconds every second

```
setInterval(function() {
    if ( new Date().getSeconds() === 0 ) onTheMinFunc();
},1000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jU3DV/)

Comment: This was something that occurred to me. I was hoping to avoid it, but I think you may be right, it may be the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: This will never work correctly - very unlikely that getSeconds will be exactly 0 ever

Comment: @ mplungjan getSeconds is a number between 0 and 59, so it will be zero 1/60th of the time

Comment: It would be very unlikely that get milliseconds would be exactly zero, but since get seconds is rounding a whole second's worth of milliseconds down, it should be correct for nearly if not all of 1 second.  Conceivably, it could miss the check for a whole second, but the amount of processing needed would probably break your page anyway.  In any case I think that checking every second is overkill for the precision you want.

Comment: @Andrew - not sure why it's so hard to get, but this will work fine, and the processing required to use the Date object once every second is so minuscule a regular wrist watch could probably do it, so that will never be an issue.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the DOM Timers API does not guarantee accuracy. [I quote](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html):

> This API does not guarantee that timers will run exactly on schedule. Delays due to CPU load, other tasks, etc, are to be expected.

Second, you have a lag on each round caused by the time `onTheMinFunc()` is executed (you only set the timeout when it's done).

So, let's say `onTheMinFunc` takes half a second to execute - you get half a second delay at each minute and it accumulates - after only 10 minutes it'll lag quite a bit. (Note, functions should usually not take more than 15ms to execute anyway to avoid noticeable lag)

Try:

```
setInterval(onTheMinFunc, delay);
```

It still won't be very accurate. You can poll on much shorter intervals and keep track of a date variable - but again - no guarantees.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. I think you right, to ensure accuracy, often better. I think something like adeneo's answer is the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: @user2014429 that's perfectly fine - I'm glad I was able to help you - best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

What you probably want is [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval):

```
setInterval(onTheMinFunc, delay);
```

As is, your code using `setTimeout` means that the time it takes to execute your `onTheMinFunc` is being added into your delay before the next one is started, so over time, this extra delay will add up.

Using `setInterval` will be more accurate, since the delay is between calls to execute the function, rather than starting the timer only after the function is finished.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something closer to this:

```
function setNextMinute() {

    // figure out how much time remains before the end of the current minute
    var d = new Date().getTime()%60000;
    //set a timeout to occur when that expires.
    setTimeout(function () {
    // recalculate a new timeout so that your timer doesn't lag over time.
        doWhateverYouWantToHere();
        // note that calling doWhateverYouWantToHere() will 
        // not offset the next minute, since it is recalculated in setNextMinute()
        setNextMinute();
    },60000-d);
}
setNextMinute();
```

caveat:  I did not *thoroughly* test this for timing.  But it appeared to work for 1 sec intervals and 1 min intervals well enough.

This has the advantage of not recalculating every second, and also not just starting a 60 second timer from whatever the current time is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight modification to your code:

```
function everyMinute(fn) {
   arguments[1] && fn();
   var now = new Date();
   var delay = 60 * 1000 - (now.getSeconds()) * 1000 + now.getMilliseconds();
   setTimeout(function(){
     everyMinute(fn, true);
   }, start);
}
everyMinute(onTheMinFunc);
```

It recalculates the number of milliseconds to wait till the next minute every time so it is as accurate as possible to the top of the minute.

Comment: Looks like a good solution. I'm testing it now. Should be able to see if the problem is solved in 15 minutes or so, I'll let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### The current accepted answer may overkill

Executing `if ( new Date().getSeconds() === 0 ) onTheMinFunc();` on each second (and forever) seems to not be a good idea.

I will not benchmark it against the following propositions, it's not necessary.

## Clues

1. Use whatever logic is necessary to calculate **the start moment**.
2. On **the start moment**

   1. Use `setInterval` for remaning executions
   2. Execute the first call

      - **Note** `setInterval` is called ASAP to avoid that time lapses.

#### If you want that `new Date().getSeconds() === 0`:

```js
var id = setInterval(function() {
    if ( new Date().getSeconds() === 0 ) {
        setInterval(onTheMinFunc, delay);
        onTheMinFunc();
        clearInterval(id);
    }
},1000);
```

#### Alternatively, you could use your own logic:

```js
var now = new Date();
var delay = 60 * 1000; // 1 min in msec
var start = delay - (now.getSeconds()) * 1000 + now.getMilliseconds();

setTimeout(function() {
  setInterval(onTheMinFunc, delay);
  onTheMinFunc();
}, start);
```

### Please check [both examples working on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9S3WG/)

The second (Example B) seems more accurate.