# Trying to just call API every minute, not when user reloads

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is what I have right now.
On my mounted() I have fetchCoins() but that makes it so whenever a user refreshes, the API is called

I'm trying to make it so the API is calledthe data is stored in localstorage, then getting the data every minute

```js
methods: {
    async fetchCoins() {
      const response = await fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=1h");
      const data = await response.json();
      this.coins = this.coins.concat(data);
    },

    setData() {
      localStorage.setItem('coin-info', JSON.stringify(this.coins))
    },

    getData() {
      let get = localStorage.getItem('coin-info', []);
      this.coins = JSON.parse(get);
      console.log(this.coins);

      setInterval(() => {
        this.fetchCoins()
      }, 60000);
    },
}
```

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/balexandre/pen/ExQwJQP

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track in localStorage about the date when the last fetch happened. Here is an example implementation:

```js
   scheduleNextFetchCoins() {
       const lastFetch = new Date(localStorage.getItem('coin-info-last-fetch'));
       
       const timeDelta = Date.now() - lastFetch.valueOf();
       const nextCall = Math.max(60000 - timeDelta, 0);
       
       setTimeout(() => {
           this.fetchCoins();
           localStorage.setItem('coin-info-last-fetch', new Date());

           this.scheduleNextFetchCoins();
       }, nextCall)
   }
```

You need to change the call to `this.fetchCoins()` in the `mounted` function for this one.

But keep in mind that there are a couple of caveats about this snippet (out of the scope of the question):

- `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are not not totally accurate time functions. They could be delayed by some milliseconds. If you are concerned about this innacuracy, have a look at some other questions that propose solutions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20502381/2886688).
- This snippet works only for a single instance of the component. Creating multiple components will result in a race condition to write into `coin-info-last-fetch`.
- There's nothing stopping the loop of fetching, not even when the component is destroyed. You need to store the timeout id returned by `setTimeout` in the data of the component to be able to eventually clear it.